# NGINX bind to a specific network interface, regardless of IP address

Tags: nginx, network-security

Is there a way to make Nginx 1.11 bind to a specific interface regardless of the IP address?

I've got a home gateway to an ISP provider; it uses DHCP client to obtain its dynamic IP address.  I do not know what that IP address is at NGINX configuration time.

Surely, there must be a way to make such a fine HTTP server bind to a specific network interface?  I know that Apache can.

Comment: Why not just bind to all?

Comment: The other interfaces are related to enterprise network (which has its own web server), test network (which has none), and a virtual network for the virtual host farm (which runs Apache).

Hence, the need to bind this Nginx specifically to the external interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit your startup sequence to run a command or script that captures the interface's IP address and writes it to a file in the format `listen <ip>:80` or whatever port you want:

```
echo "listen $(ip -o -4 a s eth0 | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d/ -f1):80;" > /path/to/some/file
```

Then just have your nginx config include that file:

```
include /path/to/some/file;
```

Obviously, you'll need to make sure the IP capture occurs before the nginx startup does.

Comment: Yep.  Examination of the Nginx machine code shows that it CANNOT bind to a specific interface.  

What a crying shame to diminish a fine product with just straight-jacket settings.